# How to get data in api with employee number instead of id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have created an api GET method to fetch child seminar table with parent users table that has `employee_number` column

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function() {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'seminar'], function() {
        Route::get("/{employee_number}", [UserProfileController::class, 'getSeminar']);
        Route::post("/{user}", [UserProfileController::class, "createSeminar"]);
        Route::put("/{seminar}", [UserProfileController::class, "updateSeminar"]);
        Route::delete("/{seminar}", [UserProfileController::class, "deleteSeminar"]);
    });
});
```

This is my Seminar model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Users;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Seminar extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'users.seminars';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'dates',
        'name',
        'certificate_number',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function seminarFiles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Users\SeminarFile", "seminar_id");
    }
}
```

This is my get method

```
public function getSeminar($employee_number)
    {
        $seminars = Seminar::with('user')->where('user_id', $employee_number)->get();

        return response()->json($seminars, 200);
    }
```

In my get method how do i compare the $employee_number value to seminar table. Do i do something like this

```
$seminars = Seminar::with('user')->where('user_id', $employee_number)->Auth::user()->id;
```

Is this the right path or should i do `where('user_id', $id)` instead

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [`Resources Controllers`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers), do not reinvent the wheel and stick to standards...

Comment: Thank you. I will take this advice as learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getSeminar($employee_number)
{
    $seminars = Seminar::with('user')
        ->where('users.employee_number', $employee_number)
        ->get();

    return response()->json($seminars, 200);
}
```

If you want to get seminars of authenticated user, use this:

```
public function getSeminar()
{
    $seminars = Seminar::with('user')
        ->where('users.employee_number', Auth::user()->employee_number)
        ->get();

    return response()->json($seminars, 200);
}
```